# Magento: get thumbnail for crossel product

Tags: image, magento, caching, thumbnails, product

I am trying to display image thumbnails for the Crossell Products retrieved using:

```
$_crossSellProducts = $_product->getCrossSellProducts();
```

After clearing the `/media/catalog/product/cache` folder and the Magento cache, this still retrieves the image placeholder:

```
$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_crossel_product, 'small_image')->resize(60);
```

The product images are displayed on the product-detail page.

How could this be solved?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, as [Amit Bera](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2940291/amit-bera) suggested, the thumbnails seem not to be available for the crossel products retrieved this way.

Got it working by loading the actual product object:

```
$_crossel_prod_obj = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_crossel_product->getId());
$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_crossel_prod_obj, 'small_image')->resize(60);
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

For get thumbnail type   used below code `$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_crossel_product, 'thumbnail ')->resize(60);`

Also....
I thought ,small image  is not available for this products.

Comment: True, the thumbnails are not available. I had to retrieve the crossel product like this to get them: `$_crossel_prod_obj = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_crossel_product->getId());` Thank you!